# Show that the class of functions is or is not compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I think the wording of this problem is the root of my confusion. The problem statement is just this:

We measure distance between bounded functions:

$f,g : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ by $d(f,g)=sup_{t \in [0,1]} |f(t)-g(t)|$

I understand this part just fine. The distance between them is the sup of the distances evaluated at all t in [0,1].

This next part throws me off.

1. Show that the class of functions {$t^n : n \in\mathbb N$} is not compact.
   There are four more problems like this. I know how to show a set is compact, but I've never seen a question regarding a set of functions. Am I looking at the range of output values the functions can take, and then checking if the distances are bounded? I don't want help solving the problem..just interpreting the problem statement. I googled "class of functions" and similar phrases, but I got no results. Likewise, a ctrl+f of my textbook returns no hits for "class of functions".

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Are you sure "continuity" isn't required from these functions?

Comment: I'm not sure what's required. I can check if a function is continuous; so far, we've been using the open set definition. I just don't know what it means to show a set of functions is not compact.

Comment: So **only** boundness is given for this set of functions, right? Nothing about continuity...

Comment: Correct. I know that t is in a closed, bounded interval.

Answer (score 1):

Convergence in this norm guarantees pointwise convergence. So, the only candidate for these functions to converge to is the function that returns zero on [0,1) and which returns 1 at 1. All subsequences converge pointwise to theis function. However, no subsequence can converge uniformly to this target function, which is what is required by the sup-norm. This sequence has no subsequential limit, and therefore it cannot be compact

Comment: Why "continuous"? Where it is mentioned in the OP?

Comment: All of the OP's functions are continuous.  He is using the norm of uniform convergence. So any limit would necessarily be continuous for the maps $t\mapsto t^n$.

Comment: He's certainly using the norm of uniform convergence but applied **only** to bounded functions: read the question. Nowhere is continuity mentioned.

Comment: Ok, but then that is *a different* argument from the one in your answer @ncmathsadist , and it requires, in several parts, of proof.

Comment: Would y'all have any books / wikipedia articles I should read before tackling this? I'm having trouble following your suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion, Don.  I have modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: That looks much better, @ncmathsadist...still, assuming all you wrote (I'm not an analysis guy), couldn't we just end the argument by remarking that if we had uniform convergence *and since the sequence of functions* $\;\{t^n\}\;$ are continuous then also the limit function would have to be continuous...and it isn't (discontinuity at $\;1\;$), then...? +1

Comment: So, for the rest of the functions I was given, since they all use the same norm, I will need to show whether or not they converge pointwise and uniformly to a continuous function, correct? If I was given a different norm, how would that change my approach?

Answer (score 0):

Let $F$ be a class of functions. That is synonimous to a set of functions. Let $f \in F$.

Since you have a distance in a linear space, you have the norm $\|f\|=d(f,0)$.

So if $F$ is compact, then for each functional sequence $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, it's possible to find such a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ that $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} f_{n_k}$ exists and is in $F$.

In another words, for each sequence $f_n \in F$ there is such an element $f\in F$ that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}d(f_n,f)=0$

Comment: So, since $\mathbb F=${$t,t^2,t^3,..t^n$}, and there is no $f \in \mathbb F$ that satisfies $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}d(f_n,f)=0   \text{, }\forall t \in [0,1]$$ then, $\mathbb F$ is not compact. Is this line of thought correct?